# Data coming back as undefined in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to pass data down to a component with react router. I've tested that the end point works correctly, so it's not a server issue.

This is my function that is supposed to grab the page data based on the ID param:

```
    instance.get(`/admin/page/${id}`).then((response) => {
      return response.data
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
    })
  }
```

And my React Route:

```
    <Route path="/admin/edit-page/:id" render={ (props) => (
      <AddEditPage {...props} page={this.setPage(props.match.params.id)} />
    )} />
```

But page is coming back undefined when I goto

> localhost:3000/admin/edit-page/1

If I `console.log(response.data)` inside the `setPage` function, I can see the correct data in the console. This is so weird.

Am I not supposed to `return response.data` ??

This is the whole `App.js` container file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route
} from 'react-router-dom'
import axios from 'axios'

import Header from '../components/Header'

import Dashboard from './Dashboard'
import AddEditPage from './AddEditPage'

const instance = axios.create({baseURL: 'http://localhost:1337'})

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      "pages": []
    }
    this.createPage = this.createPage.bind(this)
    this.getPages = this.getPages.bind(this)
    this.setPage = this.setPage.bind(this)

  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getPages()
  }

  getPages() {
    instance.get('/admin/listPages')
      .then(
        (response) => {
          this.setState(
            {
              "pages": response.data
            }
          )
        })
      .catch((error) => {console.log(error)})
  }

  createPage(page) {
    instance.post('/admin/createPage',page).then((response) => {
      this.getPages();
      //TODO: Create my own history object as props, then use router to push route.
      window.location.replace('/')
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
    })
  }

  setPage(id) {
    instance.get(`/admin/page/${id}`).then((response) => {
      return response.data
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="Router">
          <div className="Navbar">
            <Header />
          </div>
          <div className="Wrapper">
            <Route exact path="/" render={ (props) => (
              <Dashboard {...props} pages={this.state.pages} />
            )} />
            <Route path="/admin/new-page" render={ (props) => (
              <AddEditPage {...props} createPage={this.createPage} />
            )} />
            <Route path="/admin/edit-page/:id" render={ (props) => (
              <AddEditPage {...props} page={this.setPage(props.match.params.id)} />
            )} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </Router>

    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2):

In your example, `this.setPage()` is an asynchronous function. Therefore, the return value will be undefined. There are a couple different ways to fix this. One way would be to set the ‘page’ the same way you set the ‘pages’. That is, using state.

Comment: I did try that, but wasn't able to access this.props.match.params.id in the function or constructor.

Comment: Does set page need to be at the App level? Can it be within AddEditPage?

Comment: Hmm I guess it could be, but then I would have to include axios again. Does that matter? I thought it would be nice to have it within the App container.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're *calling* a function, not passing a reference to it:

```
 page={this.setPage(props.match.params.id)}
```

That's almost definitely not what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of trying different things, I finally got it working. This is how.

Instead of making another API call, I decided to use the already stored pages data in the state. I pass it down as props to the edit page:

```
    <Route path="/admin/edit-page/:id" render={ (props) => (
      <AddEditPage {...props} pages={this.state.pages} />
    )} />
```

Then inside the AddEditPage component I did:

```
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    const page = nextProps.pages[this.props.match.params.id]
    this.setState(page)
  }
```

I still don't know what is better speed wise though. To reuse the data in the state, or to make another api call for a single object.